# Dot Product with Partial Differential Question

Tags: inner-products, polar-coordinates, divergence-operator

Given: $$\vec{A}(r,\theta)$$
$$\vec{B}(r,\theta)$$
Is it always true that:

$$
\left(\vec{A}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\right)\bullet\vec{B}\overset ? =\bigg(\vec{A}\bullet\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial{\theta}}\bigg)
$$

The reason I ask is because, when evaluating: $$\vec{\nabla} \bullet \vec{u}$$

it was assumed that:
$$
\left(\hat{\theta} \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) \bullet (u_r  \hat{r}) =\hat{\theta} \bullet \left(\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial (u_r \hat{r})}{\partial \theta} \right)  
$$
See image: [Computation of the Divergence in Polar Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVgPs.png)

Image Source:

- ["Vector Calculus for Engineers", Page 61](https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/%7Emachas/vector-calculus-for-engineers.pdf)

Comment: The left hand side of your equation $\stackrel{?}{=}$ does not "compile". Presumably $\vec{A}$ has more than one component. What is $(\vec{A}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta})\,?$ Please write this out to clarify. Never seen such a differential operator. And please do not ask us to watch youtube videos to understand the question.

Comment: I scrapped the YouTube link, replaced it with an image. It comes from the definition of the gradient in polar form.

Comment: You mean *divergence* in polar form. 2D polar coordinates are not very different from 3D cylindrical coordinates. Besides: that image is not using an arbitrary vector field $\vec{A}$. It is using the *basis* vector field $\hat{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta\,.$ Since those $\hat{\theta}$ thingies always lead to much confusion I prefer the shorter notation $\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta\,.$ For more details see    [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4666592/949989).

Comment: When we apply the vector field $\hat{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta$ to a function $u$ we only differentiate $u$ w.r.t. $\theta$ and then multiply it by $1/r\,.$ That's why I find my proposed notation in the previous comment much better. No $\hat{\theta}$ thingy and no $\bullet$ is necessary.